# DateTime.Now.Year to fill maximum value in RangeValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a RangeValidator to validate that a year is between a static start year and a dynamic end year (the current year). I am drawing a huge blank for setting the maximum value in this fashion:

```
MaximumValue='<% DateTime.Now.Year %>'
```

Any help is appreciated as I usually don't set max values in this fashion.

Edit:
So I have been given the following ways to incorporate the code into the codebehind:

1. validator init event
2. page prerender
3. and i'm a newb and would just have done on page load

which is best?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET doesn't let you do this; the `<%= ... %>` syntax doesn't work either.

The easiest way is to just set the `MaximumValue` property in the code-behind, in the validator's `Init` event. (This is better than the page's `Init`, `Load`, or `PreRender` event, which would bloat view state.)

```
protected void rangeValidator_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((RangeValidator)sender).MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
}
```

By using the `sender` parameter, multiple `RangeValidator` controls on the page can all share this event handler.

If you *really* wanted to set the `MaximumValue` in the .ascx/.aspx, then take a look at this blog post: [The CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx).

**UPDATE**: Setting `MaximumValue` in `Init`, `Load`, and `PreRender` would all work. `Init` has the slight advantage that it avoids increasing the size of view state. `PreRender` has the additional *dis*advantage that server-side validation would break if view state were disabled for the validator.

Answer (score 5):

It works without codebehind

```
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" 
        MaximumValue='<%# DateTime.Now.Year %>' MinimumValue="2000"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

and call this method in the page load event

```
  DataBind();
```

Comment: @MichaelLiu - That's right, but the user put the question this way `MaximumValue='<% DateTime.Now.Year %>'
` before he/she updated it.

Comment: This may add to the view state, but is so much easier to set up and understand.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this by code behind , check for Range validator documentaion [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx)

aspx markup

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="MaxDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Some Error message" ControlToValidate="SomeControltoValidate" 
 Display="Dynamic" Type="Date" ></asp:RangeValidator >
```

code behind file.  for page pre-render event.

```
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MaxDate.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: i was going to do the code behind method as it would be easier, i was just trying to avoid 20 lines of assigning :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an `=` to cause the evaluated value to be returned by the `<% %>`.

```
MaximumValue='<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>'
```

Comment: thank you, just one problem, i get this error now:
The value '<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>' of the MaximumValue property of 'ra__curr_yr' cannot be converted to type 'Integer'.

Comment: @Guvante: AFAIK the `<%= %>` is valid to assigning to client side controls, and `<%# %>` for server side controls.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `using DateTime.Now`    to   `DateTime.Today`

```
RangeVal.MinimumValue = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
RangeVal.MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.AddYears(50).ToShortDateString();
```